# Finding whether a key is present in Json--- php

Tags: php, json, search

I'm very new to php and  I have a Json like this :

```
{
  "customer_id": "guest_user_101",
  "merchantId": "guest",
  "cards": 
  [
    {
      "card_token": "0784ba0c-dc07-489e-a57d-16dfcb39868f"
    },
    {
      "card_token": "fe4ebe01-bbb6-46b6-8e49-5c572ee20bc7"
    }
  ]
}
```

I wish to find whether there is a `card_token` in `cards`. Are there any easy and elegant way to do that? Note that there can also be a case where `cards` have empty list.

Currently I do this way:

```
$json->cards[0]->card_token
```

But I guess there will be a better solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function is_card_token_present($json)
{   
    $present = false;
    foreach($json['cards'] as $card)
        if(isset($card['card_token'])) 
            $present = true;

    return $present;
}
```

Should work :) Might need a bit of tweaking because I can't test it at the moment but the concept is there.

Comment: `empty($json->cards[0]->card_token)` is more canonical

Comment: If there's 200+ cards, it won't be